# Set of Special Unitary Matrices that are dense in SU(4) and obey certain relations

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I'm trying to find a finite set of 4x4 Unitary matricies $\{U_1,U_2,\ldots U_N\}$ such that the matrices are dense in SU(4), and obey the relations:

$[U_i, U_j] = 0$ for $|i-j|>1$

$U_iU_{i+1}U_i=U_{i+1}U_iU_{i+1}$.

$[U_1, U_N] \neq 0$

$U_NU_1U_N=U_1U_NU_1$.

Comment: How can a finite set be dense?  Or, perhaps said differently, what do you understand by 'dense'?

Comment: Sorry, to clarify I mean that after repeated applications (multiplication) of the matrices, you can approximate any point in SU(4) within some distance $\epsilon$, for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Is there any reason you expect a set of matrices like this to exist?

Comment: It seems impossible due to the third relation. Neglecting the third relation, I'm not entirely sure. It exists for SU(2). See [page 44](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0401090v4.pdf).

Comment: Correcting my now-deleted answer, without the third relation this is the Artin presentation of the braid group $B_{N+1}$. The third relation describes some quotient of this group; maybe it's possible to say explicitly what this quotient is.

Comment: If you neglect the third relation, the abstract group with the first two relations is the Artin braid group $B_N$ on $N$ letters. For $N=5$,  there are certainly representations  (The Burau representation) into $U(h)$ for suitable Hermitian forms $h$ in four variables, whose projection into $U(4)$ (a compact group) contains $SU(4)$ in their closure. See a recent paper by Curt Mcmullen (Braid groups and Hodge theory, Math Annalen ) where such constructions are given

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: If $U_1$ and $U_N$ commute, then the last relation just says that $U_1=U_N$, so I suspect the OP wants to exclude $i=1$, $j=N$ from the first relation, and then it's again not quite $B_{N+1}$.

Comment: That's correct. I don't want $U_1$ and $U_N$ to commute. I forgot to mention that. I'll edit the post now.

Comment: $[U_1,U_n]\neq 0$ follows from $U_1 U_N U_1=U_N U_1 U_N$, as for commuting $U_1$ and $U_N$ it implies $U_1=U_N$.